# Merging maps in Clojure

Tags: data-structures, clojure

I'm looking for a way to merge 4 separate lists of maps. I'm scraping a site that gives me a list of attrs in the form of `data*` below...

```clj
(def data1 '("1" "1" "1" "1"))
(def data2 '("2" "2" "2" "2"))
(def data3 '("3" "3" "3" "3"))
(def data4 '("4" "4" "4" "4"))
```

...and them I'm organizing them according to keys:

```clj
(map #(assoc {} :a %) data1)
(map #(assoc {} :b %) data2)
(map #(assoc {} :c %) data3)
(map #(assoc {} :d %) data4)
```

That code above produces the following data structure:

```clj
({:a "1"} {:a "1"} {:a "1"} {:a "1"})
({:b "2"} {:b "2"} {:b "2"} {:b "2"})
({:c "3"} {:c "3"} {:c "3"} {:c "3"})
({:d "4"} {:d "4"} {:d "4"} {:d "4"})
```

I want to combine these lists vertically, so I have the following:

```clj
(def want [{:a "1", :b "2", :c "3", :d "4"}
           {:a "1", :b "2", :c "3", :d "4"}
           {:a "1", :b "2", :c "3", :d "4"}
           {:a "1", :b "2", :c "3", :d "4"}])
```

This would allow me to iterate over the list of maps and select a specific value from each map, spitting them out on a webpage. But I'm not sure how to get the data structure I `want`. Any help is appreciated...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Its not clear to me why you would do the intermediate step of

```
(map #(assoc {} :a %) ...)
```

If your data is

```
(def data [["1" "1" "1" "1"] 
           ["2" "2" "2" "2"] 
           ["3" "3" "3" "3"] 
           ["4" "4" "4" "4"]])
```

And your keys are

```
(def my-keys [:a :b :c :d])
```

Then you can just use `zipmap`

```
(mapv zipmap (repeat my-keys) (apply map list data))


;=> [{:d "4", :c "3", :b "2", :a "1"}
;    {:d "4", :c "3", :b "2", :a "1"}
;    {:d "4", :c "3", :b "2", :a "1"}
;    {:d "4", :c "3", :b "2", :a "1"}]
```

Note the `(apply map list data)` is used to transpose the data to the correct orientation with respect to the keys.

Comment: In short, this worked after changing `(apply map list data)` to `(mapv vector data)`. The data are generated in 4 separate sexprs, actually `select` functions from the Enlive library. Each `select` pulls out a different element: first the `href`'s, then the `a` text, etc. So I have a long list of `href`'s, another list of text describing the link, etc. I `assoc` the respective keys as a way to describe the link attribute before merging them into maps.

Answer (score 4):

`Map` takes every combination of firsts, seconds, etc. from the provided collections and performs a function on each. So it's quite good for transposing collections. `Vector` is shown here as the simplest function to illustrate the transposition:

```
(map vector
  [{:a "1"} {:a "1"} {:a "1"} {:a "1"}]
  [{:b "2"} {:b "2"} {:b "2"} {:b "2"}]
  [{:c "3"} {:c "3"} {:c "3"} {:c "3"}]
  [{:d "4"} {:d "4"} {:d "4"} {:d "4"}]))

=>([{:a "1"} {:b "2"} {:c "3"} {:d "4"}]
   [{:a "1"} {:b "2"} {:c "3"} {:d "4"}]
   [{:a "1"} {:b "2"} {:c "3"} {:d "4"}]
   [{:a "1"} {:b "2"} {:c "3"} {:d "4"}])
```

`Merge` combines hash-maps:

```
(merge {:a "1"} {:b "2"} {:c "3"} {:d "4"})
=> {:d "4", :c "3", :b "2", :a "1"}
```

Combine the two for the effect you want:

```
(map merge
     [{:a "1"} {:a "1"} {:a "1"} {:a "1"}]
     [{:b "2"} {:b "2"} {:b "2"} {:b "2"}]
     [{:c "3"} {:c "3"} {:c "3"} {:c "3"}]
     [{:d "4"} {:d "4"} {:d "4"} {:d "4"}]))

=>({:d "4", :c "3", :b "2", :a "1"}
   {:d "4", :c "3", :b "2", :a "1"}
   {:d "4", :c "3", :b "2", :a "1"}
   {:d "4", :c "3", :b "2", :a "1"})
```

Comment: `mapv` rather than `map`?

Comment: Whyever would you ? There's no indication in the question how the result would be used, it could very well be needed to be lazy.

Comment: `want` is presented as a vector, and we're told it would be used to *iterate over the list of maps and select a specific value from each map*.

Comment: There's not really a way to present a want in def form to be lazy.